# 64Bit Custom pipeline not showing in ToolBox

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, custom-pipeline-component

I have created a x64 custom pipeline for Excel to XML decoding in BizTalk. I added the dll in the Pipeline Components folder in BizTalk 2013. But when I am trying to add this to the ToolBox it is not showing up. I need to the dll to be 64 bit since my OLEDB adapter is 64 bit and if I use 32 bit it will say provider is not registered on the local machine. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure the DLL is GACed.
2. Restart Visual Studio after GACing the DLL (Visual Studio actually keeps this cached).
3. Right click on the Pipeline Designer toolbox, select `Choose Items...`, and browse to the DLL using the "Browse" functionality in the selector if it still doesn't show up.
4. If it still doesn't show up after manually selecting the DLL, it likely means that you are not properly inheriting/implementing the required interfaces and base classes.  We could help you with this if you post the class definition (e.g. `public class ExcelDecoder : IBaseComponent,` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in this article and let us know what happens: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26404.biztalk-server-deploying-custom-pipeline-components-in-biztalk-server-2006-and-higher.aspx

Disclaimer, I have never built a custom pipeline component targeting x64 specifically.

However, you might be missing another gap.  Where exactly are you seeing 'provider not registered'?  Design time or runtime?  Is the BizTalk Host Instance 32 or 64?